# Check if a number is between two others

Tags: r, range

I am looking for a function that verifies if a number is between two other numbers. I also need to control if I want a strict comparison (a

I know the function `between()` in `dplyr`. Yet, I have to know the upper and lower numbers.

```
MyNumber = 8
First = 2
Second = 10
# This will return TRUE
between(MyNumber, lower =  First, upper =  Second)
# But this will return FALSE
between(MyNumber, lower =  Second, upper =  First)
# This will return TRUE. I want it to return FALSE
First = 8
between(MyNumber, lower =  First, upper =  Second)
```

I need a function that returns `TRUE` no matter what is the order.

Comment: It does not do the job I need. See examples above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
between2 <- function(number,bounds) { number > min(bounds) & number < max(bounds)} 
between2(8, c(2,10))
[1] TRUE
between2(8, c(10,2))
[1] TRUE
```

This function also deals with your added condition

```
between2(8,c(8,10))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks. It is strange that there is no 'natural' function doing that.

Comment: Maybe there is, but sometimes it's easier to build a function than to go looking for a package :)

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with a simple arithmetics:

```
between <- function(number, first, second) { (first - number) * (second - number) < 0 }
```

Here are some example outputs:

```
> between(8, 2, 10)
[1] TRUE
> between(8, 10, 2)
[1] TRUE
> between(8, 10, 12)
[1] FALSE
> between(8, 1, 2)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Nice :) `<=` should be changed to `<` to satisfy `between(8, 8, 10) == FALSE` though

Comment: @Niek fixed this part

Answer (score 3):

You could use `%in%` with the `:` function, once you now `first` and `last`:

```
first <- 2
last <- 10
number <- 8

number %in% first:last 
[1] TRUE

first <- 10
last <- 2
number <- 8
number %in% first:last
[1] TRUE


first <- 10
last <- 12
number <- 8
number %in% first:last
[1] FALSE

first <- 12
last <- 10
number <- 8
number %in% first:last
[1] FALSE
```

In a function, and `strict` lets you consider or not strict comparison:

```
my_between <- function(n, f, l, strict = FALSE) {
  if (!strict) { 
    n %in% f:l # if strict == FALSE (default)
  } else {
    n %in% (f+1):(l-1) # if strict == TRUE 
  }
}

my_between(8, 2, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
f_between <- function (num, L, R) num>=min(L,R) & num<=max(L,R)

f_between(8, 2, 10)
#[1] TRUE
f_between(6, 6, 10)
#[1] TRUE
f_between(2, -10, -2)
#[1] FALSE
f_between(3, 5, 7)
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach, it's immediate and it lets you easily deal with `NA` in `L` or `R` with `na.rm=T`. Where other would fail, mine included.